# Use of single and plural in the sentence structure "one of ______ is..."

Tags: grammatical-number

Hi I want to clarify in the following sentence:

> "One of the processes is brought by aversive emotional responses, and is likely to be controlled by the xxxxx pathway."

We usually use "One of the **__**" followed by singular verb "is". However "emotional responses" is plural? Is this correct? Second following question would be - should I still use "is likely" or "are likely"

Thanks.

Comment: The choice of *is* is predicated by the use of *one*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "*one* of the processes" is the subject of the sentence, the singular "is" should be used.

"... brought by aversive emotional responses..." serves as an [adjective clause](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adjective_clauses.htm), describing "one of the processes," so the plurality of "emotional responses" is irrelevant to the conjugation of the previous "to be."

To answer your second question, since the subject of the sentence is singular, the singular "is," as in "is likely," is indeed correct.

Answer (score -1):

Stick with *is* because *responses* is the object of the preposition *by*.